# How can I connect Oracle Jet Application with demantra database to fetch data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-jet

I am learning and making a self POC on oracle jet and i want to fetch data from any database(demantra or any db).

Comment: Please look around in the Oracle JET Cookbook:  http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=ojCollectionTable -- of course, you'll have to create your own RESTful endpoint to *actually* query the DB and send the data to your frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle JET is a pure client-side toolkit and as such, can only communicate with databases, via some kind of Web Service interface.  REST, Websocket, Server Sent Events, etc.

To interact with any database, expose the REST interfaces for the data and use normal AJAX or JET's Common Model to interact with that REST interface.